# Human Activity Recognition - How to process gyroscope and magnetometer data

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I've found many articles ([like this one](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-14715-9_5#page-1)) on HAR that mention using the gyroscope and magnetometer because it improves the precision of HAR performed just with the accelerometer. However no one mentions how this data is processed. For acceleration usually I calculate the mean, standard deviation, variance, energy and frequency domain entropy; but since the magnetometer just shows the degrees from magnetic or true North and it's not an acceleration value, does it make sense to use the same features for the magnetic field values? should I instead use the speed of variation of the magnetic field and gyroscope values? I can't find any article that explains how to process this data.